# Live AR data capture of ARFaceGeometry to a custom Metal pipeline

Tags: ios, arkit, metal

I've got a Metal pipeline working.
I'm rendering the live face geometry,
captured from the TrueDepth camera on an iPhone X.

I grab the `ARFaceGeometry`from the `ARSessionDelegate` every frame.
I pass the data to my framework into the metal pipeline.

Tho the render is at 2.5fps...

Here's the render pipeline: [PixelsRender.swift](https://github.com/hexagons/pixels/blob/master/Source/PixelsRender.swift#L125)

Data: xyz's uv's & an index array.
The `ARFaceGeometry` consists of 2304 triangles.

I timed the render pipeline:

```
[1.086ms] Command Buffer    
[0.006ms] Input Texture     
[0.054ms] Drawable          
[0.110ms] Command Encoder    
[0.123ms] Uniforms          
[0.006ms] Uniform Arrays    
[0.009ms] Fragment Texture  
[68.015ms] Vertices         
[0.002ms] Vertex Uniforms   
[0.000ms] Custom Vertex Texture
[0.027ms] Draw              
[0.036ms] Encode            
[80.207ms] All CPU
[346.936ms] GPU
[431.035ms] All CPU + GPU
[434.100ms] Total
```

It's all the vertices that take such a long time to render.
Is there a way to cache the the memory space on the GPU or something?
I've got a lot to optimise, I'm sure, tho anything obvious I'm missing?

Here's my friends face:

[image: Luma Face]

**Update (Solved)**

I was mistaking instances for triangles!

It was in the main draw func. (Thanks Ken Thomases for catching this)

```
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: vertices.type,
                              vertexStart: 0,
                              vertexCount: vertices.vertexCount,
                              instanceCount: 1 /* previously triangle count of 2304 */)
```

The new GPU time:

```
[2.769ms] GPU
```

Comment: Is `vertecies.instanceCount` ever anything other than 1? If so, did you really mean to be doing instanced rendering? It seems a lot of folks misunderstand that parameter and effectively tell the GPU to do n^2 the amount of work that they thought they were. In any case, 2304 triangles is not a large number. And the `ARFaceGeometry` docs clearly state that is always the same, at least within a given run of the program.

Comment: `vertecies.instanceCount` is indeed currently set to 2304.. So I've been rendering the full geo 2304 times on top of each other? x)

Comment: That was it! It's a 100 times faster now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were unintentionally using instanced drawing, by passing a value greater than 1 for the `instanceCount:` parameter. That basically multiplies the amount of rendering work the GPU has to do. So, if you don't actually need/want instanced drawing, pass 1 there.